# Grep to print all file content

Tags: bash, grep

How can I modify grep so that it prints the full file if its entry matches the grep pattern, instead of printing just the matching line?

I tried using `grep -C2` to print two lines above and two below but this doesn't always work as the number of lines is not fixed.

I am not just searching a single file, I am searching an entire directory where some files may contain the given pattern and I want those files to be completely printed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep`'s `-l` option to list the paths of files with matching contents, then print the contents of these files using `cat`.

```
grep -lR 'regex' 'directory' | xargs -d '\n' cat
```

The command from above cannot handle filenames with newlines in them.
To overcome the *filename with newlines* issue and also allow more sophisticated checks you can use the `find` command.

The following command prints the content of all regular files in `directory`.

```
find 'directory' -type f -exec cat {} +
```

To print only the content of files whose content matches the regexes `regex1` *and* `regex2`, use

```
find 'directory' -type f \
     -exec grep -q 'regex1' {} \; -and \
     -exec grep -q 'regex2' {} \; \
     -exec cat {} +
```

The linebreaks are only for better readability. Without the `\` you can write everything into one line.
Note the `-q` for `grep`. That option supresses `grep`'s output. `grep`'s exit status will tell `find` whether to list a file or not.

Comment: Can you modify this so that I can use another grep on whole file of first matches and then printing those whole files which matches both the greps

Comment: @AniketGupta Not so easily, but there is an alternative (see edited answer).

Comment: This should make it work with file names containing newlines: `grep --null -lR 'regex' 'directory' | xargs --null cat`

Answer (score 2):

Simple `grep` + `cat` combination:

```
grep 'pattern' file && cat file
```

Comment: But I am searching recursively in a directory

Comment: @AniketGupta Then you should have said so. Please edit your question to make things clearer.